# Python Automation image clicks

Tags: python, automation, bots

I'm trying to make a bot that clicks images/buttons when they appear on a webpage. I can't use selenium as I need to have an extension installed and cant be a fresh browser.

I got the first part to work but the loop stops after restarting to the first click action and says image cant be found. I just need the bot to continue looking for the images and clicking even if an image is clicked or not found, to continue looping.

```
import time
import pyautogui
import win32api
import win32con

time.sleep(5)


def click():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.1)

def click2():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)

def try_click_actions():
    while True:
        if click_action_1():
            print("Click action 1 succeeded!")
        elif click_action_2():
            print("Click action 2 succeeded!")
        elif click_action_3():
            print("Click action 3 succeeded!")
        else:
            try_click_actions()

def click_action_1():
    start = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('images/image1.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=.8)
    if start is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(start)
        click()
        time.sleep(5)

    

def click_action_2():
    start2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('images/image2.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=.8)
    if start2 is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(start2)
        click2()
        time.sleep(18.5)
    

def click_action_3():
    start3 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('images/image3.png', region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080), confidence=.8)
    if start3 is not None:
        pyautogui.moveTo(start3)
        click()
        time.sleep(10)
    

try_click_actions()
```